# Making a vector on condition in R

Tags: r

I'm completely new to R, have a little background in Python only.

Say I have 2 columns in my dataframe df that are

```
col1 = c(1,3,4,5,2,6,7)
col2 = c(2,5,1,5,6,5,3)
```

and I want to add a new column in df consisting elements 0s and 1s only, it takes 1 if the element in col1 is less than the element in col2, and 0 otherwise. So it should be like

```
col3 = c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0)
```

I think there's a way to do it in one line,

```
df$col3 <- c(...)
```

but I don't know how to fill in (...) part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df$col3 <- as.integer(df$col1 < df$col2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply compare the vectors themselves:

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = col1, c2 = col2)
df$c3 <- as.integer(df$c1 < df$c2)
df

  c1 c2 c3
1  1  2 1
2  3  5 1
3  4  1 0
4  5  5 0
5  2  6 1
6  6  5 0
7  7  3 0
```